# Setting a value outside the constructor in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-template

I am setting a variable outside the constructor and I am using the variable in my template, but it is not assigning. How can I achieve that?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'footer',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{id}} {{name}} {{ans}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  id:number;
  name:string;
  ans:string;
  constructor() {
    this.id = `1`,
    this.name = `App`
  }
  king = ()=>{
    this.ans = "variable";
    alert("Working");
  }
}

var sapp = new App();
sapp.king();
```

Here is [a plunker I made](https://plnkr.co/edit/JPq8W5sc8iyhLz2mfAoX?p=preview).

Comment: Do you want to set the variable in the 'king' method?

Comment: why would you explicitly create an instance of a component? You can call king method in the ctor or ngOnInit lifecycle hook.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/kv4GXiWkRimYAKTEtIZr?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
 var sapp = new App();
```

The above line is creating `new` instance of your app. By doing this you have two instance of your app. You are calling `king()` method of your newly created instance. That's why you are not getting it to work.

In order to access the same instance call `king()` from any of the lifecycle methods.

eg.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'

   ngOnInit() 
   {
   king();
   }
```

Updated [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RQQO7WSNZssnXqJNiFiC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngOnInit` method.

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, OnInit} from '@angular/core'

ngOnInit() 
{
  this.id = `1.0.2`,
  this.name = `Helical`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the variable along with declaration if you need it on page/view load. Else you can also do the same using ngOnInit but Constructor fires before ngOnInit.

```
export class App {
  id:number;
  name:string;
  ans:string= "variable";
  constructor() {
    this.id = `1`,
    this.name = `App`
  }
}
```

Now you can use ans in your template.